# Approximation of matrix in 2-norm

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces

> Given a rank-$k$ matrix $A$, find a rank-$j$ matrix $B$, where $j<k$, such that $\|A-B\|_2$ is minimal.

My idea was to choose, if

$$A=P \operatorname{diag}(\sigma_1,\ldots,\sigma_k,0,\ldots) Q^H$$

then

$$B=P \operatorname{diag}(\sigma_1,\ldots,\sigma_j,0,\ldots) Q^H$$

Is this approach correct? If so, then I would try to prove that this is actually the best approximation.

Comment: It looks like a low-rank approximation problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your approach is correct and is a standard result on Singular value decomposition. The topic is termed as Low Rank Approximation. It should be there in any standard matrix theory book talking about SVD.

Answer (score 0):

The approach is correct if you ensure that the eigen values are ordered in such a way that $\sigma_{j+1},\ldots,\sigma_k$ are the smallest possible (in absolute value)

Comment: these are not eigenvalues, since $Q\neq P$

Comment: yes, these are singular values.